# Error using coursera-dl in windows

Tags: python, python-3.x, coursera-api

I am trying to use coursera-dl in windows to download coursera videos.
I have installed coursera-dl in C:\Python34\Scripts but when i try do

```
coursera-dl -u xxx@live.com -p yyyy gamification-003
```

i am getting the below error:
importerror: no module named '_version'
[image]
Please help.

Comment: Maybe this helps: https://github.com/dgorissen/coursera-dl/issues/31
Please also paste the error instead of only a screenshot, it is convenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is, the Code is not able to find the file "_version".

I would suggest you go to coursera_dl github page  -> https://github.com/dgorissen/coursera-dl

Download zip from the link which can be found on the right side of the page.

in the zip file you will be able to find a folder by the name of "courseradownloader".

Extracts all the files in this folder into yout C:\Python34\Scripts folder.

It will work like a charm.

PS: I would suggest you use .netrc file to store Username and password.